# Unable to debug in VS2005

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2005

when i push F5 in a VS2005 web service project,
a new explorer window opens and the Web service i try to debug opens.
but the VS2005 doesn't stay attached to the new window. it just stays like i didn't run the service.
when i use the service in the new window that opened , the breakpoints in the project doesn't work.
its like ,when i pushed F5 i opened a new process that is notattached to my project 
(using "Attach to Process" doesn't solve the problem).

it worked before but now it doesn't...
the project and the service page are both "Set as Startup Project/Page".

Comment: You are running the debug build aren't you?

Comment: I've run the release build by mistake and wondered why things didn't work as expected, so it's always worth checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. it is The windows Explorer 8!
The windows explorer 8 doesn't let two projects of VS2005 be debugged together.
i had two VS2005 projects that one is the simulator of the other.
i needed both applications to run together - each project that runs (and debugged) opens a different Explorer window. The problem was that when one project opened, the other couldn't be attached to its window.

uninstall windwos explorer 8 and roll back to 7 version of explorer. it solves the problem!